# How to unittest selenium code without browser or network access while testing code in CI platform like travis-ci?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-unittest

I am **scraping** website data using selenium package in python with functions like:

```
driver.find_element_by_ ...  (...)
```

I want to test this code in travis-ci platform where it has no access to browser or network.

How to test this code? it uses the following methods to retrieve data:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element()
```

Because it processes html inside, I can't feed static fixed html data directly to it for testing. So can you suggest best way to do so?

Comment: are the website page you wanted to scrap is static page or dynamical page?

Answer (score 2):

If you can put the website page on the same machine where yous test script besides, Selenium can open local HTML file with `file:` protocol as following:

`driver.get('file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/test.html')`

Comment: In any CI process, you want to run it in the real environment. but it's good to know we can run local files with selenium! +1